# Finding a submit button with Selenium in Python3

Tags: python, html, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

I´m working with a HTML code like this:

```
<p class="inhaltstext_ueberschrift">Some Text</p><br><p class="inhaltstext">some
Text<span class="inhaltstext">
<b><LI>Some headline</LI></b>
<b><LI>Headline of searched button</LI></b>
<form action="qr_info.php" name="1312" method="post">
<INPUT TYPE="submit" NAME="1314" VALUE="Create Ticket">
```

My code for finding the Button is:

```
button = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//input[@name="1314"]')
```

or

```
button = driver.find_element(By.NAME, '1314')
```

but this doesn´t work. This is the error Code:

```
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"meth oXPathpath","selector":"//input[@name="1314"]"}
```

Can someone tell me what I´m getting wrong?

Comment: In the error, it says another locator ''//input[@name="21320"]". check where you are using that locator.

Answer (score 0):

The HTML has an input with the attribute of `NAME`, but your selector is looking for the attribute of `name`. Making the case the same in your selector may solve your problem.

Comment: Good idea, but it seems that the case does not matter.

Answer (score 0):

The name which was shown in the Source Code of the HTML file was not the real name.

I listed up all Names by:

```
elements = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, '//*')
    for element in elements:
    print(element.get_attribute('name'))
```

With that, one can easily get the correct names